# How can I send a command to a running NodeJS project from the command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, command-line-interface

I have a server project which checks it's settings file every 5 minutes to see if there are any changes, then updates variables accordingly.

However, I also want to be able to tell the server to run that function which perform this check from the command line so that I don't have to wait for the changes to take effect. What is the best way of doing this?

I could add a local net socket that listens for commands - but is there a better way that doesn't require me to write a seperate program?

Comment: I ended up using fs.watchFile for this specific problem - but if there is a way to send custom commands to a NodeJS process from command line, then that would be useful to know for the future

Comment: Simply using CURL. Add a route to your Node/Express app (like `app.get("/command")`, and then call it using HTTP with CURL from a terminal : `curl localhost:port/command`

Comment: @JeremyThille but then it would be publicly accessible and therefore insecure?

Comment: If you host it on a server, listen to localhost only and/or block external access with a firewall; if you run it on your local machine, then there's no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and pass my commands now via http and a (only locally reachable) endpoint. But since you only have to watch one file, why not use a [filewatcher](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener)?

Comment: Yes! I just implemented that - It works a treat for what I need